# Using a variable in the new media javascript object

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am actually really hoping this is a noob question. Have looked around and tried for about an hour for a solution to this but I'm getting nowhere.

Real simple. I am using Cordova to build Android App. I am going through my code and trying to clean it up and make it more reusable.

I have several views/pages that play audio files. I am using the Cordova media api as HTML5 audio is not well supported.

Anyway, I use JQuery to get the ID of heading tag and then combine it with another string to make a variable. Then I am trying to use that variable to be the source for a "new Media" object. I am definitely missing something here, because it is not working and is returning null. My code is pasted below:

```
var playing = 0;
var myMedia = null;
var mySound = $("h3").attr("id");
var soundPath = "/android_asset/www/audio/"+mySound+".mp3";
myMedia = new Media('"'+soundPath+'"', stopAudio);

function playAudio() {
switch (playing) {
    case 0: 
     myMedia.play();
     document.getElementById('play').src = "../icons/pause-btn-grey@2x.png";
     playing = 1;
     break;

    case 1:
      myMedia.pause();
      document.getElementById('play').src = "../icons/play-btn-grey@2x.png";
      playing = 0;
    break;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. I am sure it is something I have overlooked but cannot "see the wood from the trees".

Comment: I just realised that the media object will need quotes otherwise it will not be read as a string so I updated the object to reflect this and also did console log on the output. It all seems fine but tracing the myMedia object still returns null.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to say "it all seems fine". It does not. The audio does not work, either does alert(myMedia) - returns null

Comment: Moderator can close this question. What i was doing was working fine. My problem is initiating the media object in an external script. It does not work, and I have spent ours with console logs and alerts to try to figure out why. If anyone has an explanation, I would be keen to hear it. Unfortunately the script is going to have to be inline on all pages, bummer....

Comment: The first argument to the Media constructor is the path, so you should not be adding quotes around your existing string. This should be valid: new Media(soundPath)